GPyTorch Inference Time Much Longer Than Training Time
I'm working with a GPyTorch model using the Ackley function as a test case (2 features, 1 target). I'm training on 5,000 data points with an 80/20 train/test split. Training on CPU takes about 37 seconds, but inference on the test set takes around 5 minutes, which seems unusually long compared to the training time.
Here's the model I'm using:
class ExactGPModel(gpytorch.models.ExactGP):
    def __init__(self, train_x, train_y, likelihood):
        super(ExactGPModel, self).__init__(train_x, train_y, likelihood)
        self.mean_module = gpytorch.means.ConstantMean()
        self.covar_module = gpytorch.kernels.ScaleKernel(gpytorch.kernels.RBFKernel())
        
    def forward(self, x):
        mean_x = self.mean_module(x)
        covar_x = self.covar_module(x)
        return gpytorch.distributions.MultivariateNormal(mean_x, covar_x)

Issue:
Training Time: ~37 seconds
Inference Time: ~5 minutes
Question: Why is the inference time significantly longer than the training time in this case? Is there something I'm missing about how GPyTorch handles inference, and how can I improve the inference speed?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
